# Expanding the graph in Balkan FamilyTree Js library

Tags: javascript, nodes, family-tree

Can you tell me if there is any possibility of showing full family tree without collapsing the part of family nodes? I want to see the full tree without hidden nodes,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbw5Q.png)

I tried to find a specialized method for configuring branch folding in the documentation, but it was not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Zornitsa from BALKAN App Technical support team.
Showing the whole Family Tree is not possible with the current implementation. We have plans for developing a new product where this will be possible.